# Auto linebreak using action in MSC

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, msc

I am trying to draw a message sequence chart using LaTex. Currently I have some problems with a long action. How can I make it to linebreak automatically?

This is the part of the MSC (before asking, I have included the `msc` package and it compiles well)

```
\newcommand\setmscoptions{\setlength{\instdist}{5cm}\setlength{\levelheight}{1.5 \levelheight}\setlength{\instwidth}{3cm}}

\setmscoptions
\begin{msc}{Sequence Chart}
\declinst{A}{}{A}
\declinst{B}{}{B}
\declinst{C}{}{C}

\action*{This is a very log action that does not fit on one line}{B}
\end{msc}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the text in a `\parbox` works fine here.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\newcommand\setmscoptions{%
  \setlength{\instdist}{1cm}% % reduced from 5cm
  \setlength{\levelheight}{1.5 \levelheight}%
  \setlength{\instwidth}{3cm}}

\begin{document}   

\setmscoptions
\begin{msc}{Sequence Chart}
\declinst{A}{}{A}
\declinst{B}{}{B}
\declinst{C}{}{C}

\action*{\parbox{3cm}{This is a very long action that does not fit on one line}}{B}
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```